# Print zero if text is not found in a particular file

Tags: shell-script, grep

I want to print zero if `grep` is not found in a particular file

```
grep -A4 " Apple " a.txt | tail -1 | awk '{printf("%f", $4)}' >> out
```

I tried using if else condition too

```
if grep -A4 " Apple " a.txt | tail -1 ;
then 
    awk '{printf("%f", $4)}' >> out
else 
    echo 0 >> out
fi
```

So, for example, given this file:

```
Apple
is 
xyz 
abc def cost 352.271
```

My command greps for `apple` and prints 352.271. But if there's no match, I want it to print `0`.

Comment: are you looking for `grep -c` (-c ==> count) ?

Comment: Why do you want a zero?  Why not just use the exit status of `grep -q` to determine whatever else you want to determine?  (What are you going to *do* with the zero?)

Comment: The most literal way to accomplish exactly what you ask—"print zero if grep is not found in a particular file"—is `grep -q grep file || echo zero`.  Which will print "zero" if "grep" is not found in "file."  I *suspect* that's not really what you're after, but there's not enough detail provided to let me read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that what you are trying to do is this:

```
if result=$(grep -A4 " Apple " a.txt); 
then 
    echo "$result"|tail -1|awk '{printf("%f",$4)}' >>out
else 
    echo 0 >>out
fi
```

Main problem with your code is that, when you are using pipe, the exit code is always from the last command in your case `tail -1` which always `0`, hence the if condition is always true.

Another problem with your code is `awk '{printf("%f", $4)}' >> out`, here where does `awk` get its input?

Answer (score 1):

You're complicating this for no reason. First, you don't need `tail`, you can tell `awk` to run something only for the last line of input using `END`. That way, as an extra benefit, your `awk` command will already print a `0` if no match is found:

```
$ cat file
Apple
is 
xyz 
abc def cost 352.271
$ grep -A4 "badstring" file | awk 'END{printf("%f\n", $4)}'
0.000000
```

If you insist on getting a `0` only, you could do something like:

```
$ grep -A4 "Apple" file | awk 'END{k= $4 ? $4 :  "0"; print k}'
352.271
$ grep -A4 "badsting" file | awk 'END{k= $4 ? $4 :  "0"; print k}'
0
```